# Outlook 2013 and newer - VSTO - is it possible place buttons here?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

I am working on VSTO add-in for Outlook 2013 and newer and I can not find how to place my buttons to these three following places:

Fig 1: When you right-click on Outlook. I would like to extend this list.

[image: When you right-click on Outlook.]

Fig 2: When you minimize top ribbon you can see New Email button. I would like to place button below.

[image: When you minimize top ribbon you can see New Email button.]

Fig 3: When you hover contact you can see contact card. I would like to put new button next to existing icons.

[image: When you hover contact you can see contact card.]

So is it somehow possible? I was searching in FluentUI docs but without success.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that out of the box.